# looks down the bar

Tags: grammar

(A guy is sitting at the bar in a bar.)

Guy takes out his wallet and **looks down the bar**, but the bartender is nowhere to be seen.

Is **looks down the bar** correct here if I intend it to mean that he looks to the side down the bar he's sitting at? Could it also, in another context, mean to literally look down at/into the bar counter?

Comment: I would find _along_ more natural.

Comment: "Down" has many informal uses but it's seldom used to mean "along". And no - we wouldn't say that to mean "looks down _at_ the bar".

Answer (score 1):

"Down the bar" is natural in standard American English and probably more common than "along the bar," which might suggest a more precise trajectory aligning exactly with the bar.  It means to go in the direction of the longest dimension of the location and has the same meaning as in "walk down the street or walk down the hall."  It could not mean to look down into the space behind the bar where the bartender(s) stand.  To say that, you would probably say, "look (down) behind the bar."